# Are frequency and likelihood the same across the multiverse?

Tags: quantum-interpretations, probability, multiverse

My [probability text](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/188652923X) distinguishes between two interpretations of probability values:

1. the *frequency of occurrence* "as percentage of success in a moderately large number of similar situations" (coin tosses, etc.), and
2. the *likelihood of an occurrence* of a unique event (whether a skier medals at Sochi, for example),

and argues that the latter conveys no information about the former, since it is a "one-time event".

If one considers the multiverse as a whole, however, are these interpretations still distinct? In particular, is the *reason* that a unique event has a likelihood that it occurs with the corresponding frequency across all universes? Does the answer depend on [what kind of multiverse structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiverse#Max_Tegmark.27s_four_levels) is being considered?

For example, is it the case that under a many-worlds interpretation of quantum mechanics, these are indeed equivalent, because the likelihood of an event is just the quantum mechanical distribution of possible events among "worlds"?

Comment: Seems related to frequentist vs Bayes? Does the book elaborate?

Comment: @innisfree: The book is a very basic introduction, so it doesn't really address these issues.